# Jquery Remove Class Multiple Elements

Tags: jquery, addclass, element

I am setting a class to multiple elements via a Button click via the code below:

```
$('button.but1').on('click', function() {
    $(".div1,.div2,.div3").addClass("focus");
    $(".div1,.div2,.div3").css("z-index", "99");
    $(".div1,.div2,.div3").css("opacity", "1");
});
$('button.but2').on('click', function() {
    $(".div4,.div5,.div6").addClass("focus");
    $(".div4,.div5,.div6").css("z-index", "99");
    $(".div4,.div5,.div6").css("opacity", "1");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>
<div class="div4"></div>
<div class="div5"></div>
<div class="div6"></div>
<button type="button" class="but1" href="#">But1</button>
<button type="button" class="but2" href="#">But2</button>
```

The issue I am having is that I only want the `div` selected to be "focus"(the class), all the other div, not from the same group need to have the "focus" class removed.
Not sure which we to go?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can remove the already added class before adding the class to set of elements.like this:

```
 $(".focus").removeClass("focus");
 $(".div4,.div5,.div6").addClass("focus");
```

Complete Code:

```
$('button.but1').on('click', function() {
  $(".focus").removeClass("focus");
  $(".div1,.div2,.div3").addClass("focus");
  $(".div1,.div2,.div3").css("z-index", "99");
  $(".div1,.div2,.div3").css("opacity", "1");
});

$('button.but2').on('click', function() {
  $(".focus").removeClass("focus");
  $(".div4,.div5,.div6").addClass("focus");
  $(".div4,.div5,.div6").css("z-index", "99");
  $(".div4,.div5,.div6").css("opacity", "1");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the class from all the 'other' divs first:

```
$('button.but1').on('click', function() {
    $(".div4,.div5,.div6").removeClass("focus");
    $(".div1,.div2,.div3").addClass("focus");
    $(".div1,.div2,.div3").css("z-index", "99");
    $(".div1,.div2,.div3").css("opacity", "1");
});
$('button.but2').on('click', function() {
    $(".div1,.div2,.div3").removeClass("focus");
    $(".div4,.div5,.div6").addClass("focus");
    $(".div4,.div5,.div6").css("z-index", "99");
    $(".div4,.div5,.div6").css("opacity", "1");
});
```